# Javascript new Date() returning wrong date

Tags: javascript

When I am converting milliseconds to date, its creating a wrong date.

Number of milliseconds : 1460226660, which is actually: 10 april 2016. But it's showing me the following date : 17 January 1970, when I tried new Date(1460226660);

Comment: `new Date(2016, 03, 10).valueOf()` -> 1460242800000.  Your original value is wrong.

Comment: i took help of this which is showing me right date. http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=1460226660&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++

Comment: Your value is number of seconds, treated as milliseconds.  It is out by a factor of 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your value is in seconds, not milliseconds, so try multiply it by 1000.

```
new Date(1460226660 * 1000)
```

Comment: Thank u, rajesh already solved my confusion between seconds and millis. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your value `1460226660` are seconds and not milliseconds.

```js
var date = new Date(1460226660 * 1000);
document.write(date.toDateString());
```

Comment: Down votes were because this was a simple observation. You could have tried creating date object for 10th, april and check it in milliseconds.